# How can I compile and run a Java class in a different directory?

Tags: java, javac

I'm writing a makefile that compiles a `.java` file in a different directory, and then I want to run it, without changing directories. I want to do something along the lines of:

```
$(SQM_JAVA_TOOL_DONE) : $(SQM_JAVA_TOOL)
        $(shell cd /home_dir)
        javac myjavafile.java
        java myjavafile
```

where the Java file is `/home/myjavafile.java`, and the makefile isn't running from `/home`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you create an Ant script and pass the full path to the ant build.xml to compile your java files?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding the question, but you can compile with

```
javac /home/MyJavaFile.java
```

This will create `MyJavaFile.class` in `/home`

You can then run it by including `/home` on the classpath. e.g.

```
java -cp /home MyJavaFile
```

If you want to generate the class file in a different directory then you can use the `-d` option to `javac`.

Comment: I tried `java -cp ".:lib/dropbox-core-sdk-1.7.5.jar:lib/jackson-core-2.2.3.jar:lib/javax.mail.jar" /bin Client1`, but the linker spat out: `Error: Could not find or load main class .bin`.

Comment: @Andrei, just drop the "/bin" before Client, put all jars or folders with .classes you need between the double quotes of "-cp" after it just the main-classes name.

Answer (score 42):

Use the `-d` command line parameter with `javac` to tell it what directory you'd like to store the compiled class files in.  Then, to run the program, simply include this directory in the classpath:

```
javac -d some/directory myjavafile.java
java -cp some/directory myjavafile
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the existing answers, you may want the `--source-path` flag:

> ```
> --source-path <path>, -sourcepath <path>
>       Specify where to find input source files
> ```

I believe this effectively sets the package root `javac` will compile from (i.e. `<path>` will be stripped from the expected package name of the files). It's still necessary to enumerate the files to compile, and this should still be relative to the current working directory, *not* the path passed to `--source-path`.

For example, to compile and run from a project's root where source is stored in `src/` and you want it build in `bin/`:

```
$ javac --source-path src -d bin src/mypackage/*.java
$ java -cp bin mypackage.Main
```

This works even from directories elsewhere in the filesystem, e.g.:

```
$ javac --source-path /some/absolute/path/src  -d /some/absolute/path/bin /some/absolute/path/
$ java -cp /some/absolute/path/bin mypackage.Main
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using VS Code and installed [java](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java) and [code runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CodeStream.codestream) extensions. When I created new java project using the extension, it was creating the .class file in src instead of bin. To solve the issue I opened settings.json file from File > Preferences > Settings and searched for "settings" (or "code-runner"). Then I added following lines in that file.

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "java": "cd \"$workspaceRoot\\\" && javac --source-path src -d bin src\\$fileName && java -cp bin $fileNameWithoutExt",
}
```

If you don`t want to see the command that runs before code file then add these lines instead:

```
"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
"code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "java": "there is && clear added in the execution paramater"
    "java": "cd \"$workspaceRoot\\\" && javac --source-path src -d bin src\\$fileName && clear && java -cp bin $fileNameWithoutExt",
}
```

I hope this finds someone with similar issue.