# How to load .java file to compiler?

Tags: java

Ok, I am beginner in JAVA. I have just started. I downloaded Java SE Development Kit 6u21 and wrote a program, saved it in .java and try to run it, but I can not do it. What's wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Darin's answer might help you, but if not, consider telling what "I can not do it" means exactly. And also how did you try to run it.

Comment: Based on your answer to Colin: Do you have Java JDK installed and is it in your path?

Comment: I have installed it and what a heck means is it in my path?!

Comment: @hey, there are basic things that you should learn about a computer before starting to program. If you don't know what a path means I would strongly suggest you learning this before starting to write code.

Comment: I know what path means, it is C:\program files\etc... But what did he mean asking me "is it in my path"?

Comment: It's not a path, it is the PATH environment variable. See Colin's link.

Comment: I edited my answer, please see the second link too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read and follow this tutorial by Oracle: ["Hello World!" for Microsoft Windows](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html). Once you have successfully done so, you should have JDK installed and know how to run your program.

If you are still getting "'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file", try reading these: [How do I set or change the PATH system variable?](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) and [PATH and CLASSPATH](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).

Comment: I wasn't angry, frustrated at most. ;)

Answer (score 6):

You will need to compile it first using [`javac`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html):

```
javac YourClass.java
```

And then run:

```
java YourClass
```

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to do it manually, you have to use the `javac` compiler in command line like this :

```
javac package/of/your/project/YourClass.java
```

and then

```
java package.of.your.project.YourClass
```

Your class `YourClass` must have a `public static void main(String... args)` method.

If your class isn't in a package, then `javac YourClass.java` and `java YourClass` are sufficient.

You should really consider to use an IDE which will handle this for you.

---

**Resources :**

- [javac documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)
- [java documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html)

**On the same topic :**

- [Compiling multiple packages using the command line in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512603/compiling-multiple-packages-using-the-command-line-in-java)
- [Compiling/running a java program in a different directory.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415507/compiling-running-a-java-program-in-a-different-directory)

Comment: I actually think it's good for anyone to do these things manually for at least the first Hello World program, just to get to know the basics.

Comment: I agree, I was just implying that manual compilation isn't the only way to compile.

Comment: 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: You may not have defined the JDK bin folder as a part of your $PATH (or %PATH%) environment variable. See http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17824_01/dsc_docs/docs/javacaps/installing/jcapsinstgui.inst_jdk_javahome_t.html