# How to specify the Main Class name and provide arguments to my Java program?

Tags: java

There is a directory called `Programs`. Inside that I have my java program called `Main.java`. I compiled it using this command,

```
javac Main.java
```

It compiled properly without any errors.

My program takes in three command line arguments. So to run my program in a Linux machine I use this command when I am present inside the `Programs` directory,

```
java Main arg1 arg2 arg3
```

That works well.

However if I am in some other directory and try to run this program like,

```
java /home/Blake/Main arg1 arg2 arg3
```

I am getting an error like this - `Error: Could not find or load main class`

I tried this command too, but I get same error message:

```
java -cp /home/Blake/Main arg1 arg2 arg3
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Any input is well appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You want to start by reading basic tutorials on packages and class path setup. This is a super basic thing documented in countless places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You nearly did it correctly:

```
java -cp /home/Blake Main arg1 arg2 arg3
```

see [How can I compile and run a Java class in a different directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415507/how-can-i-compile-and-run-a-java-class-in-a-different-directory)